# Does this matrix shape have a name?

Tags: matrices, terminology

I'm using a lot of matrices that look like the following

$$ A_3 =
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b & b\\
b & a & b\\
b & b & a
\end{bmatrix} $$

i.e., the diagonal entries are all the same, and all off-diagonal entries are the same. They need to be non-singular, so $a \ne b$, for one thing.

If you know of a common name for this shape of matrix, I would very much appreciate your help, and references would be most appreciated!

Comment: It looks like a special-case of a symmetric matrix, but I'm not sure if there's a specific name for it. You might want to go through the list here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_matrices

Comment: Why not even dimension? I would say $aI+b(J-I)$ or $(a-b)I+bJ$

Comment: I'm not interested in even dimension right now. The name should hold for any dimension - so my question had superfluous information. 

Comment: @Gilead, that link is the kind of thing I am looking for; but nothing there matches my matrix, as far as I can see.

Comment: By the way, for this $n \times n$ matrix to be non-singular you also need $a + (n-1)b \ne 0$.

Comment: @AaronMeyerowitz not that $J$ is a standard notation for the all-ones matrix...

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but many types of combinatorial designs (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_design) come with adjacency matrices $A$ whose square $A^2$ (or $AA^T$ or $A^T A$, depending on the design) are of the required form.

Answer (score 12):

As far as I am aware, these matrices are called *Bose Mesner* matrices--For reasons that I now do not remember. However, many years ago, I wrote a short summary that is still available [**at this link**](http://people.kyb.tuebingen.mpg.de/suvrit/work/dimath/bm/)

(In particular, they form a nice algebra, their characteristic polynomial has a closed form, etc. etc.)

Comment: Looking at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose%E2%80%93Mesner_algebra it appears that Bose-Mesner matrices are somewhat more general: I think you have the case $n=2$.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to understand how the Bose Mesner algebra relates to these matrices. As yet, I don't know.

Comment: Thanks Robert---I was waiting for a comment from you, because somehow I get the feeling that 10yrs ago I heard of this name from you on sci.math or something :-) --- and of course, the general class of Bose-Mesner matrices or algebra is much richer than this special example, but this at least starts us out with some name!

Comment: In the context of association schemes, these matrices are _not_ called Bose-Mesner matrices. The matrices given do belong to the Bose-Mesner algebra of the complete graph, but I have never seen any matrix in any Bose-Mesner algebra referred to as a Bose-Mesner matrix.

Comment: @Chris: I think I then just extrapolated from the BM algebra to call these matrices BM matrices! But given the connection, perhaps it is acceptable to call them: BM matrices of type $K_n$

Comment: @SSra: I don't think you heard about them from me.  I don't recall ever writing (or reading) "Bose-Mesner" before.

Comment: @Robert: I guess, I misremembered then (merely because I used to see your name a lot on sci.math etc.); it seems the original reason where I got this name from was the following post back in the day: http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=519436

Answer (score 3):

Notice that a matrix with constant entries $b$ can be viewed as $b$ times the projector onto the vector $v=(1,\ldots,1)$. Thus your matrix is

\begin{align}
    A_n=(a-b)\mathbb{I}_n+b \,v v^\top.
\end{align}

Thus its eigenvalues are $a$, and $a-b$, and eigenvectors are $v$ and all vectors orthogonal to $v$.

Incidentally, $A_n$ commutes with all permutation matrices of the $n$-element permutation group in the $n$ dimensional representation. Thus it is a Casimir of that representation.

Comment: In numerical analysis, the addition of a $v v^T$ term is often called a _rank-1 update_. Thus, $A_n$ is a rank-1 update of a multiple of the identity.

Answer (score 0):

Circulant Matrices? What is your motivation?

Comment: I'm studying automorphisms of order 2 on certain algebraic groups. These matrices come up in that context. Circulant matrices are more general, though these certainly fit that shape.

Answer (score 0):

if $a > b$ then the matrix is a special case of a Robinsonian matrix or R-Matrix; I encountered that name  when searching for "matrix reordering" and remembered the question on MathOverflow

vis.pku.edu.cn/file/Summer%20School%202009/feket_matrix.pdf

Answer (score -1):

I think the best description would be a Circulant Matrix, as the other "unknown (google)" suggests since what you are seeing is the vector (a b .... b) shifting right 1 on each row.